# Call function when google map loads

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm using the basic initialize function from the Google Maps Developer pages. I'm a little new to using maps but I'm managed to achieve what I want from reading the developer site. What I can't find though is a way to call a function once initialize has LOADED the map. For example, I want to update directions based on values in pre-filled forms

I tried something like this...

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
    initialize();
    updateDirections();
});
```

Initialize loads the map, updateDirections is the function I want to call to put in directions and some other little things to do with my webpage, but my guess is that maps needs a little time to load, then I should call updateDirections().

How is the best way to do this? I would have thought a callback or onsucess parameter in map options would have been available.

Anyway I think what I'm trying to do is really straight forward but maybe I'm wrong, or maybe it is and I'm just searching for the wrong things. I'm sure it's been answered previously, but I can't seem to find anything that simply does what I'm trying to do.

Thanks
Bizt

Answer (score 2):

Inside your `initialize()` function, after you create the map and have a reference to it in a variable called `map`, add an event listener for the `idle` event:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce( map, 'idle', function() {
    updateDirections();
});
```

If the only thing you need to do there is call your `updateDirections()` function, you could just use it directly as the idle callback:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce( map, 'idle', updateDirections );
```

Note the use of `addListenerOnce()` instead of `addListener()`, so this event listener is only called the first time the event fires. If you used `addListener()` it would fire every time the map is panned or zoomed.